# using css, how to position image so when resizing window, image will not move

Tags: css, image, positioning

i was wondering if anyone could help me with css. ive been stuck on using background-attachment:fixed;

it just doesn't seem to work. im basically trying to make an image a link, but i don't want it to scroll so i made it into a bg image.
i have...

```
<a href="/contents/selection" title= "Manage selection." id="f-logo" style="background-image:url({{STATIC_URL}}images/flowsTab_normal.png);background-attachment:fixed;background-repeat:no-repeat;display:block; height: 90px;width: 130px;"> </a>
```

when i take out background-attachment:fixed, i see the image, but once i put it in, it disappears. i deliberately left out text between the anchor tags so the image is like a clickable link : D

ive been super stuck. help would be much appreciated. thanks! css syntax is confusing...

Comment: create a [Fiddle of this code](http://jsfiddle.net) it will be much easier to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a character to your anchor tag. A non breaking space will do the trick.

See my example on the very useful tool, [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/vn9pY/).

Comment: it still didnt work for some reason on mine. i winded up using position:relative and position:absolute and it fixed it. thanks a lot for your support though = )